# Unable to run Eagle PCB software on Fedora 32 linux Intel 64 platform (problem related to "xcb" and "QT"

Tags: linux, fedora, qt

I'm having trouble understanding console debug data while trying to get Eagle PCB layout software installed on my Dell laptop running Fedora 32. I've included console debug output below in the hope that someone can help me better understand and fix the errors.

```
[jcl@localhost eagle-9.6.2]$ setenv QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS 1 
[jcl@localhost eagle-9.6.2]$ 
[jcl@localhost eagle-9.6.2]$ ./eagle QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/home/jcl/EE/Autodesk_EAGLE_9.6.2_English_Linux_64bit/eagle-9.6.2/plugins/platforms" ... QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/jcl/EE/Autodesk_EAGLE_9.6.2_English_Linux_64bit/eagle-9.6.2/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so" Found metadata in lib /home/jcl/EE/Autodesk_EAGLE_9.6.2_English_Linux_64bit/eagle-9.6.2/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so, metadata= { "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3", "MetaData": { "Keys": [ "xcb" ] }, "className": "QXcbIntegrationPlugin", "debug": false, "version": 329988 }

Got keys from plugin meta data ("xcb") QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/home/jcl/EE/Autodesk_EAGLE_9.6.2_English_Linux_64bit/eagle-9.6.2/platforms" ... qt.qpa.plugin: Could not find the Qt platform plugin "wayland" in "" This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: xcb.

Abort (core dumped) 
[jcl@localhost eagle-9.6.2]$ echo $QT_QPA_PLATFORM wayland 
[jcl@localhost eagle-9.6.2]$
```

Here's some information showing contents of the eagle directory:

```
[jcl@localhost eagle-9.6.2]$ ls
bin  cache  doc  eagle  examples  lib  libexec  ngspice  plugins  qt.conf  README  README.jcl  resources  translations
[jcl@localhost eagle-9.6.2]$ tree plugins
plugins
├── bearer
│   ├── libqconnmanbearer.so
│   ├── libqgenericbearer.so
│   └── libqnmbearer.so
├── iconengines
│   └── libqsvgicon.so
├── imageformats
│   ├── libqgif.so
│   ├── libqicns.so
│   ├── libqico.so
│   ├── libqjpeg.so
│   ├── libqsvg.so
│   ├── libqtga.so
│   ├── libqtiff.so
│   ├── libqwbmp.so
│   └── libqwebp.so
├── platforms
│   └── libqxcb.so
├── printsupport
│   └── libcupsprintersupport.so
└── xcbglintegrations
    ├── libqxcb-egl-integration.so
    └── libqxcb-glx-integration.so

6 directories, 17 files
```

Answer (score 1):

For a number of years there have been issues between Eagle, OpenGL, and the compositors used on a number of Linux distributions.

As per the documentation for [QTWayland](https://github.com/chinmayapatnayak/qtwayland):

> The X Composite buffer integration should work on all modern X servers. It can be used with either EGL or GLX as the OpenGL backend. This must match the backend used by the xcb platform plugin. (Normally GLX is the default for Qt applications running on X11.)

In my **personal*** experience on Fedora since Eagle version 8.x it has required setting the environment variable `QT_XCB_GL_INTEGRATION` to the value `xcb_egl` at runtime.  e.g.:

```
$ QT_XCB_GL_INTEGRATION=xcb_egl ./eagle
```

This does get into *many* different nuances as to your configuration (i.e. are you using X11 or Wayland), but this has been the most consistent solution I have found tot his concern.

* Your mileage may vary

Comment: Thanks very much, Brian.  FYI, I recently updated the packages on my Fedora 32 installation using dnf. After doing so Eagle would start but then crash any time I tried to save the files. I found a way to specify X11 as the default for gnome rather than wayland and since doing so the application seems to be stable. I will try your suggestion as well and let you know of any interesting results. - Thanks again! - Jim